# Allow only one row for a particular value but not others

Tags: mysql

I have a table that keeps track of batches (of other rows in a different table).  A simplified version of the structure is as follows:

> id | type | status

There can be multiple types of batches (for different operations) and there are multiple statuses (open, completed, failed, etc).

The business logic means that there should only be 0 or 1 open batch per type, but there can be any number of non-open batches.  If there are no open batches for a given batch type when a payload for that batch type comes in then a new batch should be automatically created.

The pseudo-code for the logic is as follows:

```
SELECT batch WHERE type = (requested batch type goes here) AND status = open
if (!batch exists) {
    INSERT INTO batch (requested batch type, open)
    SELECT last inserted batch
}
INSERT INTO payload (batch ID, payload data)
```

The problem we're running into is a good old race condition where a rapid influx of new payloads when there are no open batches can result in multiple open batches being created with a single payload each, when we actually want a single batch to be created with all incoming payloads assigned to that batch.

There are a number of suggestions being discussed (LOCK TABLES, use an additional table for implementing a lock, etc) but these all seem a bit less than elegant to me.  What I really need is a check constraint, but MySQL doesn't support those.  Transactions don't seem to be a solution either, because we still get the same behaviour.

A UNIQUE composite key isn't an option either because that would only allow one of each type of status per batch type.

Is there any other way of allowing me to have only one open batch per type, but multiple non-open ones?

Comment: Have you tried `Before Insert/Update/Delete` trigger(s) ?

Comment: How about using a transaction to create the open batch if necessary ? If the commit failed, repeat it (to find a concurrently just inserted batch), or attempt to create the batch again.

Comment: Maybe you can use `INSERT IGNORE` or `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` (but you need unique key for this one) to avoid multiple batch per type? You can use a before INSERT trigger to check if one batch with current type already exist before the insert to avoid it too. Or maybe just one before insert trigger on payload table : when you insert the payload you try to get the batch id with a select -> if you have no id, you insert a new batch

Comment: http://mysqlserverteam.com/new-and-old-ways-to-emulate-check-constraints-domain/ had some potentially interesting alternative ways of emulating checks in MySQL.  Sadly the high ups have decreed that we'll use an additional table to store a lock so the pursuit of a more elegant solution has been nixed for now.